# Cual es la mejor opcion para generar un bucle

Tags: c#, windows-forms, bucles

requiero agregar un bucle a la siguiente funcion

```
protected void btnLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Nombre;
        string Apellido;
        string Descripcion;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EjemploConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        string CadSql = "Select Nombre, Apellido from Auditor " +
           "inner join Zonas on Auditor.IdArea<>Zonas.IdArea where IdAuditor=IdAuditor Order by NEWID()";

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(CadSql, conn);
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (leer.Read() == true)//extrae los datos del comando y lo guarda en al variable leer
        {
            Nombre = leer["Nombre"].ToString(); //Selecciona el nombre y lo alamacena en la variable string de Nombre
            Apellido = leer["Apellido"].ToString(); //Selecciona el apellido y lo alamacena en la variable string de Apellido
            conn.Close();
            string CadSql1 = "SELECT DESCRIPCION FROM ZONAS " +
                "inner join Auditor on Auditor.IdArea<>Zonas.IdArea where IdAuditor=IdAuditor Order by NEWID()";
            SqlCommand comando1 = new SqlCommand(CadSql1, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader leer1 = comando1.ExecuteReader();
            if (leer1.Read() == true)//extrae los datos del comando y lo guarda en al variable leer1
            {
                Descripcion = leer1["Descripcion"].ToString(); //Selecciona la descripcion y lo alamacena en la variable string de Descripcion
                conn.Close();
                if (Datos.Existe(Convert.ToString(Descripcion)) == 0) //Verifica que la descripcion no este ingresada en ls tabla
                {
                    if (Datos.ExistN(Convert.ToString(Apellido)) < 5) //Si el usuario ya se agrego 5 veces no genera el insert
                    {
                        Datos.Insert(Nombre, Apellido, Descripcion);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("El auditor ya tiene demasiadas zonas");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("La zona ya se registro");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo que requiero es agregar un bucle que repita constantemente la funcion y cuando ya no se registre otra zona para guardar se finalice la funcion, todo el codigo ya me hace lo que necesito, verificar y agregar la zona, y darle un usuario que auditara la zona.

Ya intente el foreach, el for y el while y ya no se si exista otra funcion o este realizando algo mal.

Comment: Estas haciendo el trabajo de SQL del lado de la aplicacion, puedes escribir un Stored procedure y enviarle los parametros para habilitar la insercion,  tu sP solo puede regresar un codigo para mostrarlo del lado del usuario. Y separa el llamado a la capa de datos y el console.Write en dos metodos le dara mas claridad a tu codigo.

Comment: y porque no podes hacer un for, while o foreach? como intentaste hacerlo? que errores te diio?

Comment: for = while =  foreach.. son solo distintas formas de escribir lo mismo, y eso es una iteracion.. no hay mas...

Comment: El for, while y foreach lo unico que hacen es que brincan el proceso directamente, no ejecuta lo que tiene dentro del foreach, los SP los utilice en su momento y no me salia el resultado que necesitaba, por esa razon lo hice de esta manera

Comment: Tendriamos que ver como escribiste esas iteraciones. Por lo que decis, cometiste algun error al escribirlas. O tal vez arreglar tu SP.. o sea.. la respuesta es iterar.. y para iterar se usa un iterador.. e iteradores son for, while o foreach.. que son lo mismo...

Answer (score 1):

En tu primer `if`

```
if (leer.Read() == true)
```

sustitúyelo por un `while`, eso debería funcionar a lo que entendí tu problema